How to fix: "Error dependency is not satisfiable"?
I downloaded a new version of VS Code today. When I try to install it using GDebi, GDebi says: "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libglib2.0-0 (>=2.37.3)". Note the hyphen in the first version and the dots in the second one. Is this a clue?
What can I do to fix this please?
It may be relevant that a few weeks ago I upgraded from ubuntu 24.04.0 to 24.04.1. The update ran until very late at night and I think that I was so tired I missed an error message. So something is probably wrong with my system but I don't know what it is! Everything has worked up until now and all the software updates seem to have installed correctly including the one I did before trying to update Visual Studio Code.

"Note the hyphen in the first version and the dots in the second one. Is this a clue?" Good question, but not a clue. Just formatting to keep information clear. The package name is libglib2.0-0. The package version that apt is seeking is greater than or equal to (>=) 2.37.3

In Ubuntu 24.04 the name of the GLib library of C routines package has been changed to libglib2.0-0t64 and the version of this package is now 2.80.0, but the libraries from the two GLib library of C routines packages are not interchangeable. I would expect some future update of the VSCode .deb file to address this issue.
The way out of this predicament is to install the VSCode snap package with the following command:
sudo snap install code --classic


+1: Two good answers in one!

The t64 package has a new name because the binary interface of the library changes because timestamps are now using 64 bits. These libraries are not interchangeable.

I don't trust snaps. They are older than the native packages. And I've had issues where VS Code couldn't see language servers until I installed the native version. This is a workaround, not a solution.

snap packages installed without the --classic option are sandboxed in the sense that they are confined to a restricted environment with limited access to system resources. This isolation limits their interaction with the host system, which enhances security by containing the effects of potentially harmful applications. This is better security than you would get from using some PPAs. It's also better package management. Snap packages receive automatic updates directly from the developers, reducing the chances of vulnerabilities being left unpatched.

Try this:
Download VSCode in Downloads folder.
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i code_xxx_amd64.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install

instead of xxx - enter downloaded VSCode version

When I tested it with code_1.95.3-1731513102_amd64.deb in Ubuntu 24.04 all the dependencies were installed successfully.

This worked for me thanks! However, the first 13 characters of the dkpg command are repeated (Becomes obvious when you run it)

@martinwheatman thanks! now edited
